# asp.net batch process

Tags: asp.net

I have been investigating an issue for a while now-any help would be great.

Simply put I have to run an asp.net process in the background.So currently when I postback, it does processing for a few minutes. I tried the standard approach of forking another process in the postback for the batch process and returning .However my batch process uses a ASP.NET control(specifically ReportViewer) for processing.This implies it cannot run in another thread. How do we solve this problem.Does this mean reports cannot be generated in Batch mode?.

As a compromise I am happy if the postback waits for the job to finish.But I want to display status in the client.For this while postback is on I tried to make ajax calls to server to get status.But the problem is that for a session you can only use a single thread(UI). So when I make a ajax call it waits for the postback to finish and release the thread.

I am at my wits end as this is a simple and obvious requirement

thanks

Comment: Hi I am rendering multiple reports in batch based on filters- so it takes over 10 mts

Comment: What makes the report generation slow? I mean in detail. Is 100% a black box or can you beak the process up into parallel tasks?

Comment: Hi Suppose we have a report that takes US state and date range and other parameters.Now the use may enter a list of states and set of date ranges .We have to produce report for each parameter  combination may be up to 60 reports.This definitely takes a few minutes. Also these cannot be run in parallel as a control is rendering the reports and so the report generation has to be done in the primary thread

Answer (score 0):

[image]My first thoughts.

Can you spin off a back ground thread that and pass the HTTPContext to it? Then you could send responses to the client, while the primary thread is busy?

But this artcle [Asynchronous Pages in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx) may have a better pattern for you.